# Resize image before sending to server

Tags: android, image, bitmap, network-programming

I have a very large image on my device (not taken with device camera) I need to resize the image before sending it to server. So say it is 14mb originally and I want to reduce it to 2mb. I want to resize the image without losing quality at all. What I mean is that the server will allow for zooming into the photo. So I am thinking inDensity is important. Except I don’t understand how inDensity works in this regard. Will someone please explain how I can resize the photo to 2mb but keep such a high density that the image can be zoomed with high quality? Or is that not possible.

I already know how to resize images:

```
public static Bitmap resizeImage(String file, int reqHeight, int reqWidth) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqHeight, reqWidth);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your code:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myImage)
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());

ContentBody image = new InputStreamBody(in, "image/jpeg", "filename");
```

It worked for me!

Comment: Thanks. What does it do? Are you able to explain why it works?

Comment: The method compress accept the next variables:

compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)

Once you have you bmp compressed you can attach in the content body of a request. In your case It wouldn't be necessary because you only need the bmp.